# Open "Download" Prompt after processing PNG or PDF file in PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Finally, after weeks of self study I've managed to get PhantomJS (running in NodeJS) to process a file, with attributes, output as a PNG or PDF and this is working perfectly.

However, I've been stuck the last few days and hoping someone can give me a pointer.

When PhantomJS has created the PDF, AND my childprocess has completed, how can I show a dialog box asking the user if they wish to download the file?

I've used the following code:

```
childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, 
function(err, stdout, stderr) {
     console.log('Child Processing complete!');
          download('myservername','test.png',function(){
               console.log('done')
          });
     }
);
```

With the "download" function as the following:

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
var r = request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
r.on('close', callback);
});
};
```

But I just can't seem to get a prompt on the screen asking me to download "test.png"

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

*** EDIT ***

Actual code here:

This is the page that calls:

```
var util = require("util"),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs'),
request = require('request'),

url = require('url'),
http = require('http');


var phantomjs = require('phantomjs'),
path = require('path'),
childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess2 = require('child_process');


var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
var r = request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
r.on('close', callback);
});
};

var binPath = phantomjs.path;

http.createServer(function(request,response){

console.log("Webpage was called");

var childArgs = [path.join(__dirname, 'tst2.js'),''];
childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, 
function(err, stdout, stderr) {
console.log('Child Processing complete!');


download('[here is the url of my server with filename.png','test2.png',function(){
               console.log('done')
          });

 });
 response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
 response.write("Processing Server");
 response.end();
 }).listen(8080);
```

and the phantomJS page is here:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1663, height : 768};



page.paperSize = {
width: '11in',
height: '8.5in'
}

page.orientation='landscape'

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
console.log('::loading', requestData['url']); 
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
console.log('::rendering');
page.render('test.png');
phantom.exit();
};

var content='';
content += '<html><head>'
content +='</head><body>';
content+='<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 results">'

content+='<div class="col-md-8 detailsPanel">'
content+='</div>'

content +='</body></html>';
page.content=content;
```

Like I said, they both work perfectly, the webpage I call is running on port 8080, I can see the console.logs appearing in a command box on Windows Server, the PNG file is rendered perfectly, but after that it just hangs there and I get no download prompt.

Comment: Not sure why you're mentioning PhantomJS at all. You're simply asking how to download a file from a node.js server, right? I presume the user uses a browser to open the node.js page and do some stuff, right?

Comment: 100% right, yes I'm using Node.js which runs PhantomJS to create the PNG/PDF.  So it's Node that does that and not PhantomJS?

Comment: Let's see if I understand you correctly. You're accessing a page with a browser. This page is created through a node.js server. The node.js server can also spin up a PhantomJS instance to create a PDF of some other website. This PDF must be stored as a file, because PhantomJS doesn't have the capability of rendering a PDF in memory. What hinders you from making that generated PDF file downloadable through common node.js means? On the other hand, if you're generating PNGs, then you have the possibility of sending them as a Base64-encoded string to node.js without writing them into a file.

Comment: Artjom, you've described the scenario perfectly, that's the exact process.  What's hindering me is that that above code simply doesn't provide a Download prompt after it's completed.  I've modified my example above to show exactly what I'm doing, hopefully this highlights something I'm doing wrong.  Thanks for your assistance, VERY much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you should show the browser side of things.

Comment: OK, have added that.